# Make react wait for all partial pages to start rendering

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reactjs, webpack

I currently want to add some react components to my asp.net page.

It consists of various partial pages which are loaded into the page as well.

The problem I am facing is connected to partial pages, webpack and react. I am using webpack to generate a bundle which also contains all react components.

In one of these components which I take for example now, I am waiting for the window load event before I render the component on a div, which is part of a partial page.

However, considering I am loading the bundle on the .cshtml which also renders the partial pages, the window load function is firing before the partial page is loaded and therefore before the div is available.

React is therefore showing an error, mentioning that the target container is not available.

How can I get around this issue? Is there an javascript event I could use to wait for this target container?

Answer (score 0):

one way is to call React mounting in the same place your mounting div is

`<div></div><script>mount react</script>`

or use onshow event

`<div onshow=" ... call script " />`

another option is in react to wait for div to become available and use setTimeout for waiting, I am not aware HTML has the event for specific div not loaded, as it cannot reference it